# How to create Facebook test user with specific profile details?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

if I call Facebook API to create a new test user like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?
installed=true
&name=FULL_NAME
&locale=en_US
&permissions=read_stream
&method=post
&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

the user is created however the profile details contains only some basics such as gender/name/birthday:

```
{
"id":"someID",
"name":"deleteme",
"first_name":"deleteme",
"last_name":"deleteme",
"link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/profile.php?id=someID",
"birthday":"08\/08\/1980",
"gender":"female",
"email":"deleteme\u0040email.net",
"timezone":0,
"locale":"cs_CZ",
"updated_time":"2012-07-27T13:41:38+0000"
}
```

Is there a way how to create a Facebook test user with richer profile details such as 'middle_name' , 'bio'?

I've tried to call this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?
access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
&permissions=read_stream
&method=post
&name=deleteme
&installed=true
&gender=male
&middle_name=jantar
&bio=mojebio
&political=sharks
```

but it still creates a test user with the profile as with the first call ('middle_name' and 'bio' is missing). Is it a limitation of Facebook API or I am missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fb-zombie](https://github.com/gepolv/fb-zombie) (NodeJS package) will do the trick for you. Disclaim: I am the author of fb-zombie.

Comment: nice but we can not set any other details but the name ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the app dashboard @ https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/roles - In the bottom row you can create new test users and login as the test user. This allows you to edit everything on the test user profile just like a normal account.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I am aware of that. What I am looking for is a way how to define it programmatically by an Facebook API call.

Comment: It doesn't allow enter work and education things on profile